# What does this notation mean? $f(x|\theta)=\frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}I_{(0,\theta)(x)}$

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

Particularly I want to know what the meaning of $I_{(0,\theta)(x)}$ is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called the indicator function. It means:
$$
I_{(0, \theta)}(x)=\begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{if } 0<x<\theta\\
0, \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I don't think it's very common that the $(x)$ part is in the subscript too (as in your question).

Using the indicator function the following are for instance equivalent:

$$
f(x|\theta)=\frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}, \quad 0<x<\theta
$$
and
$$
f(x|\theta)\frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}I_{(0, \theta)}(x), \quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think it is it. Just like here:http://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node16.html